# Weighted mean from data

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis, data-analysis

Suppose we have 3 experimental groups measuring "x", they measure

$$x_1=\mu_1\pm \sigma_1$$

$$x_2=\mu_2\pm \sigma_2$$

$$x_3=\mu_3\pm \sigma_3$$

In the 3 experiments, we have done N measurements of "x". We do know that we have the best estimate of "x" weighting the three means or averages $\mu_i$ with the variance. But, suppose we provide a statistical "weight" (probability or reliability) of those 3 values, e.g. 0.25, 0.50 and 0.25 to the first, second and third. More generally, we give weights or probabilities $w_i$ to those calculations. How can we calculate the right weighted mean including both, variance and the probabilistic weights $w_i$? How does the solution change if we have different sample sizes in the 3 different experiments, i.e., how is the solution modified when we have sizes $N_1, N_2, N_3$ in the 3 experiments instead of the same number N of observations/measurements?

Remark: I have written the error in the mean/average as $\sigma_i=s_i/\sqrt{N}$

Comment: What is your definition of *statistical weight* in this context?

Comment: [Cross Validated,](http://stats.stackexchange.com) which is the statistics SE, is probably a better home for this question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is free of physics and is best suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The weighted mean of three values is given by
$$ \bar{x} = \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{3} x_i \alpha_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{3} \alpha_i},$$
where here $\alpha_i$ represents the weight that you give to each measurement.

If you wished to just find the weighted mean from your data as you presented it originally, then the weight $\alpha_i = 1/\sigma_i^{2}$.

If you then wish to insert *additional* arbitrary weightings, $w_i$ to each point then the weights will multiply each other. i.e. $\alpha_i = w_i/\sigma_i^{2}$.

Here I am making the assumption that this is what you mean by a "weight" and not that there is some extra systematic uncertainty in the measurements that is shared in the proportions you suggest between the three measurements. *If that were the case* then you would form the weight by adding the appropriate systematic error in quadrature with $\sigma_i$.

As to the last part of your question I am a bit puzzled. If you are using the fact that $\sigma_i = s_i/\sqrt{N}$ (I assume $s_i$ is the standard deviation *of the population* right?), then the possibility of different sample sizes is already incorporated into this formula - the experiment that take a larger number of measurements will presumably return a smaller value of $\sigma$ (if $s$ stays the same).

Comment: Yes, I used a bad notation with the standard deviation. Just an additional question, Rob Jeffries. Suppose the same 3 experiments. Suppose we want to combine the three samples of order N of the same statistic in the following way: you weight the first with 1/6, the second with 2/6 and the third with 3/6, what is the best estimate of the average of the statistic $$Y=1/6x_i+2/6y_i+3/6z_i$$, where $ x_i, y_i, z_i$, with i=1,..., N are the measurements of the 3 teams (those which give $x_1,x_2,x_3$. Would it (and why) be Ok if we calculate the average and standard deviation of those combinations?

Comment: @riemannium I am not clear how this relates to the question I have answered. Perhaps you should ask it as a new question? If $x$, $y$ and $z$ are supposed to be measurements of the same thing in different experiments, then of course you can weight them however you wish.

Comment: $x_i, y_i, z_i$ are 3 differents order N-samples measuring a same quantity. $x_i, y_i, z_i$ have different averages and standard deviations, the question is: what is the best combined average and its (statistical) error? Should we combine in quadrature the 3 $s_i/\sqrt{N}$?

Answer (score -1):

The way that I would approach this is to calculate $\chi^2$ with

$$\chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N\left({p - x_i \over \sigma_i}\right)^2$$

where $p$ is the best value for the fit and $N$ is the number of measurements $x_i$ with error $\sigma_i$.

Now with a computer or Excel sheet I would plot $\chi^2$ as a function of $p$.

As you know the value of $p$ for the lowest value of $\chi^2$, which we refer to as ${\chi_{min}^2}$, is the best fit.

To get the uncertainty you look to see the range of $p$ values for which 
$$\chi^2 <{\chi_{min}^2}  + 1$$

This will give you the range for your error bars for $p$.

This is a good general method for fitting data, but it gets more complicated when you fit more than one parameter and parameters can depend on each other. A good place for more information about this is [the Numerical Recipes Book](http://www.nr.com) by Press, Teukolsky $et al.$ and [here on the web](http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Wall2/Wal3_4.html)

Comment: Formula for chi *squared* is incorrect!

Comment: I refer you to the advice at the end of your answer. Chi-squared is the sum of $(p-x_i)^2/\sigma_i^{2}$. Reduced chi-squared is that divided by the number of degrees of freedom (is that what your undefined $n$ is?). The formula you have referred to for an error estimation uses the *un*reduced chi-square though - so there are still two mistakes here.